# Как выбрать записи с дублирующими полями из выборки записи по определенному условию в Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Существует таблица с миллиноами записей.

например, такая выборка

```sql
select c.id, c.mobile_phone, c.last_name, c.email
from user c
group by c.id, c.mobile_phone, c.last_name, c.email
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

занимает минуты.

Необходимо выбрасть записи с одинаковым **mobile_phon**e, а из получившейся выборки выбрать записи - у которых одинаковый Email.

пробовал так

вот так получаю одинаковые записи по указанному номеру тел.

```sql
select * from (select * from user where mobile_phone = '78987787878') ou
where (select count(*) from user inr
       where inr.email = ou.email) > 1;
```

и так

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY email, mobile_phone
        ORDER BY email, mobile_phone) AS Row_Number
FROM (select * from user where mobile_phone = '000023323232') as "c*";
```

но он не показывает дубликаты с email

У 5 пользователей - один и тот же номер телефона.
Из этих 5 пользователей - 2 имееют одинаковый Email - они то и должны попасть в выборку.

```sql
select * from (select * from employee where
                                          mobile_phone = '23434302722') ou
where (select count(*) from employee inr
       where inr.email = ou.email) > 1;
```

Это работает не на всех версиях postgresql.

PostgreSQL 14.7  - работает.

PostgreSQL 13.7 - не работает.

Есть ли идеи как это сделать ?

Comment: *Необходимо выбрасть записи с одинаковым mobile_phone, а из получившейся выборки выбрать записи - у которых одинаковый Email.* То есть нужны ещё два запроса? И обязательно чтобы последующий строился, используя предыдущий как источник записей?

Comment: да. У меня есть строки с одинаковым номером мобильного телефона. А в этих строках есть  поле email. так вот некоторые пользователи из этого набора - имеет одинаковый Email.

Comment: Как-то странно это всё. А озвучьте-ка собственно задачу, а не только свои предположения, каким путём её следует решать...

Comment: *У 5 пользователей - один и тот же номер телефона. Из этих 5 пользователей - 2 имееют одинаковый Email - они то и должны попасть в выборку.* Надо сразу решать ЭТУ задачу, наплевав на все предыдущие выкладки.

Comment: я поэтому и спросил совета

Answer (score 2):

Получить список `(mobile_phone, email)`, встречающихся более одного раза.

```
select mobile_phone, email
from user c
group by 1, 2
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Получить отдельные записи-дубликаты.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM user t1
JOIN ( select mobile_phone, email
       from user c
       group by 1, 2
       HAVING count(*) > 1
       ) t2 USING (mobile_phone, email)
```

Comment: не отвечает на вопрос. мне не нужны все записи, мне нужны записи по определенному условию,  то есть по определенному номеру мобильного телефона. я вверзу показал вариант, но он не работает на версии PostgreSQL 13.7

Comment: @skyho Я не понял, а что мешает добавить в мои запросы эти самые "определённые условия"? Ну и вообще полезно прочитать [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) и выполнить пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: я у же нашел решение. однако count(*) - медленно работает.

Comment: @skyho Небось нет подходящего индекса?

Comment: однако таблицей пользуются многие сервисы и ставить еще один индекс ? зачем ? таблица работает на запись. перестройка индекса занимает время во время модификации существующей записи и вставке новой. там и без этого хватает индексов. поэтому и нужно было другое решение. без использования count.

Comment: @skyho Ну тогда решение на основе WHERE EXISTS.